# Save Data from WinForms Controls to a SQL Server Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-express

So I am just getting started with this. New to .NET, SQL Server, C#, VB.NET, etc and the closest thing I have to related to this is some experience with MS Access and the VBA that relates to that and MS Office automation.

So I do have Visual VB.NET 2008 Express installed, SQL Server 2005 express installed, and I do know how to start a brand new project in VB.NET, and then add the database to the solution explorer, modify the tables/fields, etc. I know how to create a WinForm, add some controls (and name them and whatnot).....

So in MS Access I know how to use VB in the Code-Behind-Form to use the form in an unbound manner, and insert data into the tables via Visual Basic with SQL statements. I am looking to be able to begin the same sort of thing here, because I guess I have to start somewhere?

Comment: Check out http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorials/adodotnet/lesson01.aspx

Comment: and http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040614.htm

Comment: @echo - those would both be pointworthy answers...

Comment: @echo...thanks for the resources! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bit overwhelming, but I'd start with the videos here: http://windowsclient.net/learn/

and in particular, look for the data videos at the bottom of this page.

http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx

Comment: thank you very much for the resource! i will certainly take advantage of it, and learn as much as I can there! thanks!